# jquery mousedown event is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my full code but cursor is not changing even "mousedown" event is triggered. After you release mouse button, so "mouseup" is triggered, cursor is changing.

How can I fix this?

```js
$('#testing').on('mousedown', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer');
}).on('mouseup', function() {
  $(this).css('cursor', 'crosshair');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="testing" style="width: 100px; height: 200px; background: red"></div>
```

Comment: Working fine in my computer. Did you got any error?

Comment: I placed your code in an executable snippet where it appears to work fine. Check the console for errors in your page. Also ensure that you're including jquery.js and have put the code in a document.ready event handler.

Comment: Include your main `<script></script>` tags at the bottom of your `<body></body>` tags and `jQuery` in your `<head></head>` tag.

Comment: i.e http://localhost/index2.html is not working but file:///F:/index2.html is working properly. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#testing').on('mousedown',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).css('cursor','pointer');
        }).on('mouseup',function(){
            $(this).css('cursor','crosshair');
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="testing" style="width:100px;height:200px;background:red"></div>
</body>
```

The above code works fine.

Comment: I just noticed if you open html file directly then it works.

Comment: But if you open that file with Xampp it doesn't

Comment: i.e http://localhost/index2.html is not working but file:///F:/index2.html is working properly. Any idea?

Comment: Please check if you are loading JQuery properly.

Comment: jquery is properly added and I can see Cursor changes in inspect mode